# Include both foreword and introduction in small report

Tags: academic-writing, structure, introduction

I am writing a school report about a company, and the report must be 10 pages or less. My instructors want me to include who wrote which sections in the report, when we started the work, etc.

Because of the 10-page maximum, I think I can include these formal requirements in the introduction; however, I have seen others write these information in a separate section called either *Foreword* or *Preface*.

I think it's redundant to have both a Foreword and an Introduction in such a small report, but is it acceptable to use a Foreword in small school reports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Foreword would be a good place for the more technical details you mentioned.

That will let you focus on what you're supposed to in the Introduction - a summary of the overall work.